# Generate silence audio files with Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, filesystems, air

I want to build an air app that takes input (for example a list of filenames to be generated) from the user and generates sound files with desired naming. The sound files should be an "empty/silence" sound (wav, aif or mp3). Is it possible the generate such a file? If not, can I use an existing sound and embed it into the app and have that as a source when generating the files?

The purpose of this is to get a structure of files ready in the project that will be replaced by our Sound Director. This way, we can trigger all sounds before they are created.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

```
public var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

//setting mic silence to 100 means no sound is collected by the mic
mic.setSilenceLevel(100, 200);

//or mic.gain = 0 will collect no sound
mic.gain = 0;

mic.rate = 44;

mic.setLoopBack(true);
Security.showSettings("2");
mic.setLoopBack(false);

mic.setUseEchoSuppression(false);
mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, activityHandler, false, 0, true);
mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler, false, 0, true);


private function activityHandler(event:ActivityEvent):void {
   trace("activityHandler: Gain:" + mic.gain);

}

private function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void {
    trace("statusHandler: " + event.code);
}
```

Comment: So, this will make it possible for me to record sound. The thing I really want is for my app to generate a couple of silence audio files depending on the user input. The input is not the microphone, rather a possibility to define the names of the files. Sorry if it sounded like I was looking for the sound input.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean. What will the user input be and how will this effect the silent file?

Comment: The input is just a list of names that will be the name of the files. My question is about generating these files. Creation and saving the files to the file system.

Comment: Look at http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858
for an idea on how to create a wav encoded silent bytearray.

Then encode the wav to mp3
http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/

Then save the mp3 file using fileReference.save